# How to make a translucent image in pygame dynamically

Tags: python, image, pygame, transparency, blit

I'm working on custom gui components within pygame, and when making the slider component, I am giving the slider a `Draw(parentSurface)` function which draws the slider on to the parent surface at it's stored location.

Now this works, but the slider stores two images:

- a slide image that is dynamically made from tiles to match the slider's given length, measuring with a width of the given length, and a height of 3 pixels; and
- the "select" image, which is just a small 8x12 indicator to show where the slider is.

The problem is that when I `Draw(parentSurface)` I do this:

```
def Draw(self, parsurf):
    '''draw the element on parsurf at the given location'''
    w1 = self.slider_img.get_width()
    h1 = self.slider_img.get_height()
    w2 = self.select_img.get_width()
    h2 = self.select_img.get_height()
    self.image = pygame.Surface((w1, h2 + h1))
    self.image = ColorMod.Transparency(self.image, 0)
    self.image.blit(self.slider_img, (0, self.image.get_height()-h1))
    x = self.value / self.conversionratio
    self.image.blit(self.select_img, (x- w2/2, 0))
    if self.debug_on:
        print "attempting to blit to the given surface"
    parsurf.blit(self.image, self.loc)
```

However, it blits with a black background on the `self.image`. I want that to be translucent, so that the background can show through where there is nothing on `self.image`. Should I just drop having `self.image` and draw the `self.slider_img` and `self.select_img` directly to the parent surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the image transparent by calling `self.image.set_alpha((0,0,0))` Also in `self.image = pyame.Surface` you need to change it to `self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height), pygame.SRCALPHA)`
I'd also recommend getting rid of `self.image = ColorMod.Transparency...`

Answer (score 0):

If the `Surface` object that the `self.slider_img` name refers to is created dynamically, when you first create the `Surface` instance you should call `Surface.convert_alpha` to get a `Surface` with an appropriate pixel format for per-pixel alpha values.  Then you should be able to set the alpha on a pixel-by-pixel basis as needed.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha

Comment: As far as my understanding goes if you are using Windows it works, however, if you are using Ubuntu (haven't tried on other Linux os) using `Surface.convert_alpha()` does not work.